# Python: Pulling Data from Process Threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures, multiple-processes

How do I pull data from a thread that's located within a process? I'm trying to start multiple processes and within each process, create threads to do work. My multithreading knowledge is very limited and this is as far as I can get.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
from dataclasses import dataclass

# Ping Output:
'''
Pinging google.com [142.250.113.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.113.100: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=104
Reply from 142.250.113.100: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=104
Reply from 142.250.113.100: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=104
Reply from 142.250.113.100: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=104

Ping statistics for 142.250.113.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 27ms, Average = 26ms
'''

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Ping():
    name: str
    ip: str
    response: bool = False

def ping(target):
    cmd = subprocess.run(f"ping -n 2 {target}", shell=True, capture_output=True)
    out = cmd.stdout.decode()
    for line in out.splitlines():
        if "Reply from " in line:
            line = line.split(" ")
            input = Ping(name=f'{target}',ip=line[2][:-1], response=True)
            output.append(input) # Trying to append data to the output list.
            break

def thread(targets):
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as execute:
        results = [execute.submit(ping, target) for target in targets]

targets = ["google.com", "amazon.com"]
output = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = mp.Process(target=thread, args=(targets,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(output) # This will not output any data from the ping function.
```

From this code, I want to append formatted data from the ping function to a list. If I do the same thing without using mp.Process(), it works. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue

def count(num, qq):
    qq.put(num)

def thread(numbers, q):
    qq = queue.Queue()
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as execute:
        results = [execute.submit(count, num, qq) for num in numbers]
    q.put(qq.get())
    qq.task_done()

numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=thread, args=(numbers,q))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(q.get()) # This should contain 'one', 'two', 'three'.
```

Comment: to pass data between independent processes and threads you need to use some type of queue structure which allows for non-interfering writes and reads.  As written this question is too broad for an answer here.

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I've done some research into queues and see that there are multiprocessing queues and thread queues. I'm looking to take all output from a thread queue and then pass it to a multiprocess queue. I've added some code above to hopefully better explain what I'm trying to do, using the queues you described.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mix multiprocessing and multithreading.